# Как в Linux(wayland) настроить срабатывание горячих клавиш при отпускании(как в windows)?

Tags: linux, fedora

Недавно установил Fedora 28 c gnome + wayland. При установке выбрал переключение раскладки по `ctrl + shift`. В результате у меня не работают все комбинации `ctrl + shift +`, например `ctrl + shift + N` в браузере. Насколько я понимаю, это вызвано тем, что комбинация срабатывает при нажатии, а не отжатии кнопок.

Подскажите, можно ли как то настроить мою ОС так, чтобы все комбинации работали?

**PS**

Отказываться от переключения раскладки по ctrl + shift не хочу.

Comment: ctrl+shift ломает все комбинации с контролом. Самого бесит когда сажусь за комп босса.... ни  ctrl+o ни ctrl+c - подпишусь, может кто знает

Comment: Переехал на LShift + RShift, не нарадуюсь!

Comment: win+space - как дефалт ведь чем не удобен? на шапке уже 6 лет... под пальцами все ммыслемые комбы.

Comment: @Hellseher я просто привык к другой комбинации. И хочу ее. Вот хочу и все тут =)
Ну и самое главное, я хочу, чтобы у меня не отваливались все комбинации, в которых используются кнопки переключения раскладки.

Comment: @Viktorov после vim tmux screen emacs spacemacs windows... понятие "привык" стерлось. а так дерзайте только по опыту, может занять уйму времени...

Comment: Попробуйте удалить раскладки и заново настроить.

Comment: @sanmai к сожалению, так просто оно не решается.

Answer (score 2):

Самая удобная и ни с чем не конфликтующая клавиша для переключения раскладки - Caps Lock.

В этом случае стандартный функционал капса по-прежнему будет доступен с зажатым шифтом (от него обычно больше вреда чем пользы, так что таким образом вы убиваете сразу двух зайцев).

Answer (score 1):

В данной ОС при использовании ctrl+shift для переключения языка блокируются все остальные шорткаты которые содержат эти клавиши. Единставенным решением было и пока что остается перевесить смену раскладки на другие клавиши (дефолт super + space вроде), можете конечно попробовать еще поставить [патч](https://habr.com/post/87408/) который фиксит этот баг но помогает не всем

Comment: Эту статью я тоже читал, к сожалению этот путь мне не подходит. У меня Fedora и wayland

Comment: @Viktorov я понимаю, но для Fedora и Wayland таких патчей не встречал и решения вопроса тоже, все советуют просто менять шорткаты на другие

Comment: Это для слабых духом =)

Comment: @Viktorov возможно, но этот баг тянется по версиям уже много лет и как-то его никто не фиксит :( только для убунту патч напилили и то энтузиасты которым надоело